# JS help with selectively escaping html into preview area

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, html-parsing

I've been having this problem for a while now and nobody can seem to answer me fully...

I am building a forum with a simple textarea editor, and would like a preview area that updates when you type, as it does here at stackoverflow.

```
    var text = $("#edit").val();
    $("#preview").html(text);
```

As it is, the above code works fine, until you start inputting html. I want to allow basic formatting such as bold and italics, as well as support for adding in <code> tags.

EVERTHING WITHIN the code tags needs to JUST be TEXT, but the jquery above is telling ALL of my output/preview text to be put through as html - so whether I put "`&lt;`" or "`<`".

I have tried `.replace(/</,"&lt;")` methods, and RegEx methods but nothing seems to have worked yet.

I am after something very similar to how the preview area works here - if that's any help - but I'm hoping someone will be able shed some light on how I might do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you do not need to allow html and be as benevolent as browsers are. Your implementation can be **extremely strict**!

When you are extremely strict, your formatting job is very easy. For example you can only accept this syntax`[tag=parameter]` and `[/tag]` where `tag` can be `u,i,b,c` (c for color) and parameter can be anything except `]` or/and use special characters that should not appear often in normal text.

Then you can create some rules, assign priority to them and process the text based on that priority.

[code] is for multiline blocks (cannot be combined with others)
` is for inline code blocks (cannot be combined with others)

`*` is for bold text
`**` is for italic text

Now you simply need to find the tags in code and format the text accordingly:

```
function textify(text) { return $('<div/>').text(text).html(); }

function formatText(text)
{
    if (text == '') return '';

  var start = text.indexOf('[code]');
    var end = text.indexOf('[/code]', start);
    if ((end > start) && (start >= 0))
    {
        return formatText(text.substring(0, start))
            + '<pre>'
            + text.substring(start + 6, end)
            + '</pre>'
            + formatText(text.substring(end + 7));
    }

  text = text.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s|>)\\*\\*(\\S.*?\\S)\\*\\*($|\\s|<)', 'gim') , '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3');
  text = text.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s|>)\\*(\\S.*?\\S)\\*($|\\s|<)', 'gim') , '$1<em>$2</em>$3');

    return text;
}
```

And in your event handlers:

```
$("#preview").html(formatText(textify(text)));
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was after! Thanks so much Jaroslav :) One last thing - how would I change `**bold**` to [b]bold[/b] with that regex?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer for a standalone HTML sanitizer written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the innerText (IE) and textContent (w3c) DOM properties. They set/retreive only text, not tags and comments.

http://blog.coderlab.us/2006/04/18/the-textcontent-and-innertext-properties/

EDIT: I just noticed you want *some* HTML. In that case you need a much more complex solution than you can write on your own. You will need to investigate existing solutions like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/). I believe the one used here on stack overflow is also open-source but I'm not sure what it's called or where you'd find the documentation. I can recommend ckeditor though, it's very powerful and does support selective filtering of allowed tags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm still learning... :( ...so any code examples would help massively.

Comment: there's an explanation of an equivalent jQuery method called .text() here: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

There are many pitfalls to allowing selective html. Since, in your own words, you are still learning, i would suggest you go another way.

Instead of allowing selective html, create your own syntax, **[like bbcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode)** and then convert that to the tags you allow.

This will be much easier for you to control.

Comment: I have tried this using $("#preview").text(text);, but the only problem I face is THEN turning the code back in to html...